# /Users/DylanRichards/.profile:source:2: no such file or directory: QSTK/local.sh

Tags: shell, command-line, sublimetext, sublimetext3, quantitative-finance

I'm going to open this up again. I installed this thing called QSTK for some financial calculations. Now every time I open my terminal, I get this error:

```
/Users/DylanRichards/.profile:source:2: no such file or directory: QSTK/local.sh
```

Because of this error, I am unable to run programs in Sublime Text as well.

How the heck do I get rid of this?

**Latest**

After trying KEYSER's suggestion, here are the contents of the .profile file:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
source QSTK/local.sh

PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Darwine/Wine.bundle/Contents/bin/
```

Comment: This little annoyance is the only trace of QSTK on my computer. How do I find and edit ~/.profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSTK seems to have injected some line into your profile file, which is loaded by the terminal at startup. That line is trying to run a script which doesn't exist.

To get rid of the error remove line 2 in `.profile` (and possibly surrounding, related, lines).

It's a hidden file, so you can e.g. open it from a terminal. for example:

```
open -a "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/" ~/.profile
```

if that's the name of your sublime app (tab to autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find and edit ~/.profile?

In Terminal:

```
$ cd ~
$ touch .profile
$ open -e .profile
```

This will open the `.profile` file in TextEdit for your editing enjoyment.
Once you have completed your editing, save the file in TextEdit and then, in Terminal:

```
$ source .profile
```

This should avoid the need for a system restart but always a good idea to do a restart anyway when playing with fundamentals like `.____` files.